# RUL-05717: The identifier "Header.Teachers.Courses" is not valid here

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-adf, jdeveloper, oracle-rules

I am trying to add rules in my Oracle dictionary through programming in ADF and JDeveloper:

```
    Rule rule = ruleset.getRuleTable().add();
    rule.setName(aliasRule);
    rule.setAlias(aliasRule);
    rule.setPriority(property);
    rule.setAdvancedMode(true);
    rule.setDescription(description);
    return rule;
```

then:

`diccionaryRules.validate(exceptions, warnings);`

I have three warnings with the same message:

`RUL-05717: The identifier "Header.Teachers.Courses"` is not valid here.

Where in my **Oracle.rules** file I have three `viewobjects` connected by links through `private key` `ids`:

1. HeaderVVO
2. TeachersVVO
3. CoursesVVO

And the route is correct: ***`Header.Teachers.Courses`***.

I created an expression from the follwoing path:

***`Header.Teachers`*** by:

```
Expression ePath = simpleTest.getExpressionTable().get(0);
ePath.setValue("Header.Teachers");

// Here comes some validation
List<SDKWarning> warnings = new ArrayList<SDKWarning>();
List<SDKException> exceptions = new ArrayList<SDKException>();
ePath.validate(exceptions, warnings);
```

it doesn't give warnings, but this:

```
ePath.setValue("Header.Teachers.Courses");
```

gives the above warning.

I don't know why I get these warnings.

Comment: How to find out all the definition route expressions?

Comment: Relationships between view objects are handled by view links, which define a relationship between two view objects based on sets of entity attributes from each. Like entity associations, these can range from simple one-to-many relationships based on foreign keys to complex many-to-many relationships.

Comment: Yes I have two links in place, one between header and teachers and the other between teachers and courses

Answer (score 0):

You should presume that most of the people trying to answer this question (myself included) while having a good understanding on ADF, don't know much about Oracle Rules.

That being said, this looks like a problem on Rules side, rather than on ADF. As I see you are using view objects, you can probably test this integration logic from Business Components Tester and you can inject your Rules logic through application modules custom methods.

Bottom line, you are building a Rules client from java, this is not directly related to ADF. If you can make your client work from a java  main(String[] args) method, it will work from ADF too.

Comment: Well in a matter of fact I am using the oracle rules sdk and using java code from main method as you can see through the codes snippets I had provided in the question.